# Alipay notify url not being called

Tags: php, payment-gateway, alipay

Alipay notify url not working i.e. is not being called. I am using aws linux server. No firewall issue because site is working form remote location also. I have checked apache access logs and found no log for notify url. I am using testing credential of Alipay.
Here is an Alipay redirection link that might help you :

```
https://mapi.alipay.net/gateway.do?_input_charset=utf-8&currency=USD&notify_url=http://52.xx.xx.xx/payment/alipay/?task=alipay.notifyurl&out_trade_no=559a50fe904bb&partner=2088101122136241&return_url=http://52.xx.xx.xx/payment/alipay/?task=alipay.returnurl&service=create_forex_trade&sign=b7e6b53c64b3c18b0995038b67144d44&sign_type=MD5&subject=Package&total_fee=0.01
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome. It might be an issue where contacting Alipay support is reasonable. If you do post the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

For testing environment of Alipay, the payment gateway is different from the production environment. The link would be:

```
https://openapi.alipaydev.com/gateway.do?
```

For more details, you may visit: http://blog.sanuker.com/?p=551 & http://blog.sanuker.com/?p=995
The tutorials are pretty clear and easy-to-follow, I hope these help!